# Create object tree from URLs

Tags: javascript, string, loops, object, recursion

I have a array of URLs like this:

```
const urls = [
  'src/components/index.js',
  'src/components/style.css',
  'readme.txt',
  'photos/something/somwhere/why.jpg',
  'places/something/home,
];
```

And I want to have output like this:

```
{
  'src': {
    'components': {
      'index.js': true,
      'style.css': true
    }
  },
  
  'readme.txt': true,
    
  'photos': {
    'something': {
      'somewhere': {
        'why.jpg'
      }
      'home': {}
    }
    
  }
```

Where the files in the end should have value true and the empty folders should have an empty object as a value.

So far I tried to do it with nested loops but it always fails. The best option that I had this far was this but it's not complete.

```js
const result = {};

const urls = [
  'src/components/index.js',
  'src/components/style.css',
  'readme.txt',
  'photos/something/somwhere/why.jpg',
  'places/something/home',
];

const urlArr = [];

urls.forEach(url => {
  const items = url.split('/');
  urlArr.push(items);
});

for (let i = 0; i < urlArr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < urlArr[i].length; j++) {
    let item = urlArr[i][j];

  }
}


console.log(urlArr);
```

If it's possible to do with outer way it would be great too (say recursion or other stuff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checks for '.' to decide if file.  Note that this is not a reliable check.  This looks like part of a build pipeline, so there should already be a way to determine files from folders.

You don't need a recursive function. The path can be iterated over without branching:
splits the urls by '/' to get the paths to traverse (and gets the base filename)
Traverses into the object and sets the values, creating objects if path doesn't exist yet.

```js
const urls = [
  'src/components/index.js',
  'src/components/style.css',
  'readme.txt',
  'photos/something/somwhere/why.jpg',
  'places/something/home',
];

const root = {}
for(const url of urls) {
  let ptr = root
  const stack = url.split('/'), basename = stack.pop()
  for(const p of stack) ptr = ptr[p] = ptr[p] || {}
  ptr[basename] = /\./.test(basename) || {}
}
console.log(root)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a lot of different ways, however this is how I would do it.
`H` & `T` stands for `Head` & `Tail` and are standard names for when designing recursive function that operate over lists.

```js
const urls = [
  'src/components/index.js',
  'src/components/style.css',
  'readme.txt',
  'photos/something/somwhere/why.jpg',
  'places/something/home',
];

const recursiveAssign = ([H, ...T], target) => {
  if (H.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
    target[H] = true;
    return;
  }
  
  target[H] = target[H] || {};
  if (T.length > 0) recursiveAssign(T, target[H]);
}

const createTree = (paths) => {
  const acc = {};
  for (let path of paths) {
    recursiveAssign(path.split('/'), acc);
  }
  return acc;
}

console.log(createTree(urls));
```

Or if you prefer a less verbose way of write the same solution.

```js
const urls = [
  'src/components/index.js',
  'src/components/style.css',
  'readme.txt',
  'photos/something/somwhere/why.jpg',
  'places/something/home',
]

const recursiveAssign = ([H, ...T], target) =>
  H.indexOf('.') !== -1
    ? target[H] = true
    : T.length > 0
      ? recursiveAssign(T, target[H] = target[H] || {})
      : target[H] = {}

const createTree = ([H, ...T], acc = {}) => (
  recursiveAssign(H.split('/'), acc),
  T.length > 0
    ? createTree(T, acc)
    : acc
)

console.log(createTree(urls))
```